# Power BI to Analysis Services not Refreshing

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

At present, I have a dashboard connected to reports as seen below:

[image]

It would appear, even though all 3 are connected to the same live azure analysis services instance, the report on the right does not refresh live, but only once every several days.

Is there a setting that I missed that would permit connecting to azure analysis services in a more live way than simply connecting to it?

Comment: I face the same issue with direct query when connected to on premise databases. your comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is configured for a live or DirectQuery connection, datasets are refreshed approximately each hour or when interaction with the data occurs. You can manually adjust the refresh frequency in the Scheduled cache refresh option in the Power BI service.

When you refresh data, you are updating the data in the dataset that is stored in Power BI from your data source. This refresh is a full refresh and not incremental.
For a live connection to Analysis Services, the dataset definition comes from Analysis Services directly.

For more details, refer “[Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data)”.

Hope this helps.